# Shell script runs php files over and over again

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I have a ridiculously simple shell script, nothing more than a few instructions to run some php files ...

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd /home/************** // Just for privacy here
php cron-cpt.php
php cron-lvt.php
php cron-plots.php
php cron-m.php
php cron-a.php
```

The script is called metrics.sh which is chmod'd and just sits in my local binary folder.

If I run the script from the command line, it works perfectly.

If I add the same script to the cron tab to run once a day, it runs over and over. I assumed the cron was the same as invoking it manually from the command line?

I'm using the same user to invoke in cron as logged on cmd line and have tried as root and a standard user, but the same results prevail.

Google has not been helpful with this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your cronTabs:

```
0 1 * * * /home/metrics.sh
```

Change the location to your metrics.sh's location.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why moving the metrics.sh file would make a difference?  My crontab already has a similar entry to the one you have shown.

Comment: you can keep your correct `metrics.sh` location its does not matter.
I mean change the location on the code for the cronTabs.

Comment: This is the current crontab entry ...  * 1 * * * /home/********/metrics.sh (The **** are just for privacy, it points to a real folder in effect).  My point is, it works fine when run from the command line, the scripts just repeats over and over when run from cron

Comment: so change it to: `0 1 * * * /home/********/metrics.sh` This will run on every 01:00.
in your cronTabs command u give an order that in each minutes in hour 01 the code will run.
that's mean 01:00, 01:01, 01:02 and etc..

Comment: With respect, I know how the crontab works, * or 0 at the beginning should make no difference.

Comment: The script runs fine, at 1am (coincidently as you used), however it runs, and runs and runs, over and over without stopping.

Comment: @Stephen, please listen, * mean `minute (from 0 to 59)`,
From what i understood you want the code run once a day so change the first * to the minute you desire the command will run

Comment: I'm being an idiot and owe you an apology.  I should have thought before I spoke.   It's trying to run the script 60 times at 1am ... Again, my apologies.  I should have seen something that simple.